# How to convert this prototype function into es6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype

```
// Converts snake-case to camelCase
String.prototype.toCamel = function () {
  return this.replace(/(\-[a-z])/g, $1 => $1.toUpperCase().replace('-', ''));
};
```

When I do the following:

```
// Converts snake-case to camelCase
String.prototype.toCamel = () => this.replace(/(\-[a-z])/g, $1 => $1.toUpperCase().replace('-', ''));
```

I get this error:

> modifiers.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

How I'm using that `toCamel` function:

```
// Add style to coin
export const setStyle = (id) => {
  switch (id) {
    case 'basic-attention-token': return style.basicattentiontoken;
    case 'bitcoin-cash': return style[id.toCamel()];
    case 'deepbrain-chain': return style[id.toCamel()];
    case '0x': return style.zrx;
    default: return style[id];
  }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Comment: The question's title is misleading. In your example you don't convert anything to ES6. You replace a regular function with an arrow function, which doesn't make any sense in this case.

Comment: An arrow function is es6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrow functions have lexical binding, so you can't use `this` in the way that you want to. In the case you have `this` is undefined and you can't read property 'replace' of it.

Comment: So there is no way to accomplish this then? It has to stay with `function`?

Comment: @LeonGaban that's correct, currently you would have to continue using `function`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using an Arrow function.

An arrow function expression is lexically binding the `this` value. So, the value is bound to `undefined`. You have to use the normal function.